# Unity android manifest upload issues

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, oculus

I am trying to upload my application on Oculus store but I get the following errors:

[image: AndroidManifest]

I have read the issues but none of them are included in my Manifest. I do not need these permissions either in my application. So how do I rectify something that is not already present in the manifest?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vr.headtracking" android:version="1" android:required="true" /><!-- Request the headset DoF mode -->
    <!-- Request the headset handtracking mode -->
    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon">
        <activity
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:configChanges="locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|mcc|mnc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|touchscreen|uiMode"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="com.oculus.intent.category.VR" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog" android:value="false" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.vr.application.mode" android:value="vr_only"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.oculus.supportedDevices" android:value="quest|quest2" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.oculus.vr.focusaware" android:value="true" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The permissions are added by the dependencies of your app. An android manifest file is automatically merged with the manifest files of its dependencies.

The top manifest file has the priority and can alter the values of the manifest files in its dependencies.

To remove a permission, use the `tools:node="remove"` tag. For example, to remove the `RECORD_AUDIO` permission, add this line to your app's manifest file between the `<manifest>` XML tags:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" tools:node="remove" />
```

Check out the android developer guide for more information:
[Merge multiple manifest files](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#merge_rule_markers)

Comment: Thank you I will add this for all 4 permissions and then test it.

Comment: You may also need to add the schema to the manifest: `<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">`